# C# NetworkStream - data smaller than buffer size

Tags: c#, networkstream

If I have a buffer size of eg 2048 and send a message like "hi" and then another "hi", how does the client know where the first message ends and where the next begins? I read that some people recommend sending the length of the data but it seems unneeded since the client somehow knows where the messages end anyways.

Write code:

```
byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hi");
client.GetStream().Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
```

Read code:

```
if (stream.DataAvailable) {
    byte[] data = new byte[2048];
    stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    OnIncomingData(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length));
}
```

Notice that I send 4 Bytes but the receive buffer is 2048 Bytes. How does the server know when to read? Shouldn't I receive "hihi"?

Comment: The return value of Read() tells you how many bytes were read.   Store that in a variable and pass that as the third parameter to GetString().

Comment: you didn't answer my question but you did solve my problem, which is nice :-)